# Image of the room appearing incorrectly for no apparent reason

Tags: game-maker

**In the game, when I call the room (room_Corrida) from the room of the selection menu, it was for that to appear:**

[image]

**It turns out this is how the room appears:**

[image]

The effect is as if it had a white rectangle the same size as the room, with less than 100% opacity.

When I start the room immediately (I put it first), it appears normally. The room also appears normally when I have the room called directly after the start menu. It only appears wrongly when I call it after the game selection menu.

**Code that makes the room appear wrong (from the selection menu):**

```
if(mouse_x>=1601 && mouse_x<=1917 && mouse_y>=762 && mouse_y<=1077){
    room_goto(room_Corrida);
}
```

**Code that makes the room appear correctly (from the home menu):**

```
if(mouse_x>=room_width/7*1 && mouse_x<=room_width/7*2-1 && mouse_y>=room_height/10*1 && mouse_y<=room_height/10*2-1){
    room_goto(room_Corrida);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using draw? if yes, try using `draw_set_colour(c_white)` before drawing this whole text. I think the problem could be that you are changing the draw colour somewhere in the code but not changing back to white before drawing the whole ranking on the room.

Comment: Apparently it was a bug. I deleted the room and created it again and went back to normal.